# Checking several tables when updating table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, left-join, coalesce

I am trying to create a script, which will update column lang_id in table static if static.method_id = methods.method_id and if methods.mm_id = languages.mm_id and if languages.is_default = 1. But this one is not working, tell me please, why?

```
UPDATE s
SET s.lang_id = IFNULL(l.lang_id,1)
FROM static as s
JOIN methods as m
ON m.method_id = s.method_id
JOIN languages as l
ON m.mm_id = l.mm_id AND l.is_default = 1
```

upd. I am using MySQL
Getting error in

```
'FROM merchants__payment_methods_static as s
JOIN merchants__payment_methods as '
```

That's what phpMyAdmin tells me

Comment: This code will not work in MySQL.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Also, explain what "not working" means.  If you are getting an error, then show the error.

Comment: What is `t` in your code?

Comment: @forpas typo, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT` joins:

```
UPDATE static s
LEFT JOIN methods m ON m.method_id = s.method_id
LEFT JOIN languages l ON m.mm_id = l.mm_id AND l.is_default
SET s.lang_id = COALESCE(l.lang_id, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, in MySQL, the following is syntactically correct:

```
UPDATE static as s
JOIN methods as m
ON m.method_id = s.method_id
JOIN languages as l
ON m.mm_id = l.mm_id AND l.is_default = 1
SET s.lang_id = COALESCE(t.lang_id,1);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it is not changing 0 in lang_id to 1, if l.is_default was not found

Comment: Probably, you want a LEFT JOIN (although I'd just do two UPDATEs)